# I need to access the title of a selected row of a Table View outside the TableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to access the title of a selected row of a Table View.
But the issue arises when i need to access it **outside the TableViewDelegate**, i.e. : cellForRowAtIndexPath, didSelectRowAtIndexPath,  etc.
Is there anyone who could help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When exactly? Has it been selected by the user? What if nothing is actually selected? What did you try? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What do you mean outside? Why?

Comment: you need this in button action , or else

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is, I have a tableview which stores diff kind of info and certain cells contain a button to open up some other view controller. I want to access the title of that particular cell when a button inside the cell in triggered. I think I'm clear. @Wain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
- (IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender {
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *selectedindex = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
   UITableViewCell *Cell  = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
}
```

Comment: I know this is possible when we want to access the content inside a tableview function (like cellForRowAtIndexPath or didSelectRowAtIndexPath). I want the cell title to be available at a buttons click. This button is inside the cell which i have created programmatically from inside the tableview function cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think this will surely help you.

Comment: there is still a problem. tableview won't be available inside the ButtonAction().

Comment: Have you created an IBOutlet of your tableview ? If not then create and then you will be able to access tableview for sure.

Comment: IBOutlet of your tableview ?

Comment: Yes you will have to create an outlet of your tableview in your .m file

Comment: It did work. I didn't notice it earlier. Thank you @Maulik for helping me figure it out.